# Basis of column spaces of row equivalent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be row equivalent matrices.

Prove the following statements,

1. A given set of columns of $A$ is linearly independent if and only if the set of corresponding columns of $B$ is linearly independent.
2. A given set of columns of $A$ forms a basis for the column space of $A$ if and only if the set of corresponding columns of $B$ forms a basis for the column space of $B$.

For part 1),

We can apply elementary row operations onto $A$ to form $B$. 
So, $E_{n} E_{n-1} ... E_{1}A = EA = B$

Let $C_{1},C_{2}, ... ,C_{m}$ be linearly independent columns of $A$, then
\begin{align}
\lambda_{1}EC_{1} + \lambda_{2}EC_{2} + ... + \lambda_{m}EC_{m} = 0 \implies E(\lambda_{1}C_{1} + \lambda_{2}C_{2} + ... + \lambda_{m}C_{m}) = 0 \implies E^{-1}E(\lambda_{1}C_{1} + \lambda_{2}C_{2} + ... + \lambda_{m}C_{m}) = E^{-1}0 \implies \lambda_{1}C_{1} + \lambda_{2}C_{2} + ... + \lambda_{m}C_{m}=0 \implies \lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = ... = \lambda_{m}=0 \implies EC_{1},EC_{2},...EC_{m}
\text{are linearly independent columns of B}
\end{align}

The proof for other direction is similar to the above proof.

But i'm having difficulty to prove part 2).

We know that a given set of columns of A forms a basis for column space of A implies that the corresponding columns of B is linearly independent.

How do i show that the corresponding columns of B spans the column space of B?

Edit: My proof for part 2)

Let $D_{1} , D_{2}, ... , D_{K}$ be the columns of $A$, where $k$ is the number of columns of $A$.

Suppose span({$C_{1},C_{2},...,C_{m}$}) = column space of $A$.

Let $u$ be an arbitrary element of the column space of $B$.

Then,
\begin{align}
u = \mu_{1}ED_{1} + \mu_{2}ED_{2} + ... \mu_{k}ED_{k}
= E(\mu_{1}D_{1} + \mu_{2}D_{2} + ... \mu_{k}D_{k})
= E(\rho_{1}C_{1} + \rho_{2}C_{2} + ... \rho_{m}C_{m})
= \rho_{1}EC_{1} + \rho_{2}EC_{2} + ... \rho_{m}EC_{m}
\in span(\{EC_{1},EC_{2},...,EC_{m}\})
\end{align}

Let $v$ be an arbitrary element of span({$EC_{1},EC_{2},...,EC_{m}$}).

Then,
\begin{align}
v = \mu_{1}EC_{1} + \mu_{2}EC_{2} + ... \mu_{m}EC_{m} 
= E(\mu_{1}C_{1} + \mu_{2}C_{2} + ... \mu_{m}C_{m})
= E(\rho_{1}D_{1} + \rho_{2}D_{2} + ... + \rho_{k}D_{k})
= \rho_1(ED_{1}) + \rho_{2}(ED_{2}) + ... + \rho_{k}(ED_{k})
\in \text{column space of } B
\end{align}

Hence, span({$EC_{1} , EC_{2} , ... ,EC_{m}$}) $=$ column space of $B$.

The proof for other direction is similar to the above proof.